# Why aren't my variables defined when I try to print in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I'm new to Python and I'm writing a code to show how money a person loses when they play a game of Lucky Sevens. Here is the code:

```
import random 

# ask for the input
def main():
    money = int(input("Enter the amount of money would like to lose:"))
    global max_money 
    max_money = money
    global count_max 
    count_max = 0
    global count
    count = 0 

# loop 

    die1 = random.randint(1,6)
    die2 = random.randint(1,6)
    count += 1
    while True:
        if die1 + die2 == 7:
            money += 5
        else:
            money -= 1
        if money > max_money:
            max_money = money
            count_max = count

print("You have gone broke after", str(count), "rolls")
print("You should stop after", count_max, "when you had $", max_money)

main()
```

Whenever I try to execute the code, I get an error message in the terminal stating that the variables, "count", "count_max", and "max_money" aren't defined. I even tried making the variables global within the main function and I still get the same message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See [Python Scope & the LEGB Rule: Resolving Names in Your Code](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/).

Comment: Did you intend those two `print()` statements to be part of the `main()` function?  Because they aren't.

Comment: Don't use `global` IMO -- it's sometimes recommended to beginners as a way to try to avoid learning how scoping works, but as a beginner you should be trying to learn how these things work instead of being just mystified when they don't.  :)  Like John said, your problem is fixed just by indenting those two `print` lines, since then the `print`s happen in the same scope where the variables are defined (and crucially, *after* they have been defined rather than *before*).

Answer (score 2):

Your variables are defined inside the `main` function, so they won't be defined until you have called that function.  You are calling `main()` after trying to print, so they aren't defined yet.

Call `main()` before your `print` lines.

Comment: Or indent the lines so they're part of `main()`, which is probably what was intended.

Comment: @Barmar I did indent the print like you suggested and now the terminal is telling me that they are "unreachable"

Comment: @Pislibsco did you indent the `main()` after the prints? That should stay where it is. Also, your `while` loop will run forever, since it's `while True` and has no `break` statement.

Comment: you're missing something that breaks out of the loop when your money reaches 0.